# How to convert mysql queries to CDbCriteria in yii?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

These are my mysql queries.. I hope you can give some answer.

```
SELECT  a.*,
c.name AS barangay_name,
d.name AS municipal_name,
e.name AS province_name,
f.name AS region_name

FROM location a
INNER JOIN barangay c ON c.id = a.barangay_id
LEFT JOIN municipal d ON d.id = c.municipal_id
LEFT JOIN province e ON e.id = d.province_id
LEFT JOIN region f ON f.id = e.region_id
ORDER BY TRIM(a.name) ASC
```

Comment: what did you do so far?

Comment: I've already tried to convert it directly at my model. but i don't know how to use and convert the alias of the tables.. i'm very new in yii so i like to know how.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I will just leave this here:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder

Good luck :)

Comment: also, t stands for the current table as alias in criteria if needed